# Crystal Reports 2008 Runtime : Load Report Failed in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm facing a strange issue with Crystal Reports in my .NET App. I have many legacy reports designed with Crystal Reports 2008. They have formulas which use functions from a custom UFL written in Java (for now, reports are generated inside a web app using the JCR so it runs fine).

We are planning to move the report generation with .NET as a rewriting of our app is starting (and we are moving to .NET). But both versions (the legacy one and the rewrited one) will coexist for some time on our customers' environements

The problem is that some reports are loaded correctly even if we have functiosn from Java UFL in formulas (i dynamically rewrite formulas before generating the PDF) and some others not. For one of my report, the same formula used in the main report doesn't trigger an error when i call the **Load** but trigger an error (about missing UFL) when present in a subreport (the error is triggered when i try to get parameters from the main report).

Exception (in fact it's the inner one as the main exception is Load Report Failed) when the formula is in the main report :

```
Caractère ) manquant.
Détails : errorKind
Erreur dans le fichier TMSCI_02R0_LST_PROBLEMS_GB_Bis {7F68B0B3-7264-43EE-848A-5D5D4A4D30CD}.rpt :
Erreur dans la formule DONE_DATE: 
'stringVar ls_ChaineDate;
'
Caractère ) manquant.
Détails : errorKind
```

Exception when triggered by the presence of the function in a subreport formula :

```
L'UFL com.oriam.tm.crystalreport.jcr.OriamLibrary qui implémente cette fonction est manquante.
Erreur dans le fichier TMSCI_01R0_CRA_OVER_GB {865A324D-856F-4865-A972-1137CAD00F7A}.rpt :
Erreur dans la formule SELECTIONNED DATE: 
'stringVar ls_ChaineDate := "";
'
L'UFL com.oriam.tm.crystalreport.jcr.OriamLibrary qui implémente cette fonction est manquante.
```

I need the report to work through JCR **AND** .NET runtime. As i rewrite formulas using UFL functions dynamically, it's not a problem on that side... But is there a way to allow the SDK to load a report without checking formulas ? Does anyone have an idea of what i can do to solve this issue ?

Comment: Are you sure it is not simply an error in the formula? Maybe a null value or an incorrect format of a value...

Comment: @heringer Yes I'm sure... The same report works well when used inside the Java Crystal Runtime. What is surprising is that with the same formula in 2 different reports (among others) one will load normally and the other not... And for 2 reports which fails loading, the one with the formula in the main report will raise an exception "A" but the other with the formula in a sub report will raise an exception "B"